# issue on connecting mySql Database to ASP.net webapi, database connection succeeded but list of databases not retrived

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api

[Database succeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8w7i.png) 
[But List of Database not retrived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfEXr.png)

[this was the code I have used to connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDCS3.png)

[I already installed these below NuGet packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ51c.png)
I expected to connect database table and stored procedure to my asp.net project but not able to retrieving

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I already shared code ""this was the code I have used to connected"" please click above this line